# Fixed menu not working inside pusher

Tags: semantic-ui

In my code I have a `sticky menu` to be fixed like a sidebar. I want to have the menu like [semantic-ui](http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html) website.

But, the fixed property only works outside `.pusher` element. Just like the top fixed menu, in my example.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/planetadeleste/4huedm7e/)

How can I fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue.  Did you ever find a solution?